# How can I get my API KEY on the food2fork site after signup?

Tags: api-key

I have searched all over on the web site but I can't find my `API KEY`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login in your account and you should see your API Key in:

http://food2fork.com/F2F/user/api#

[image]

Comment: thank you @ijball, but my api key indicates `None`  Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I wasn't given a key when I signed up through facebook. Then I created a new login ID, signing up with my email address, and -- bingo!